# How to to upload a Python code including an OpenAI API key to my GitHub Repository with out OpenAI recognizing it as a Security leak and disable API

Tags: python, github, web-applications, streamlit, openai-api

I need to upload a Python script of a web application including an OpenAI API key to my GitHub Repository to deploy it in the Streamlit community cloud. But, when I deploy it, it works correctly only the first time. Since OpenAI recognizes it as a security breach. I get an email notification from OpenAI as below.

[image]

I get the following error when I Run the Web App in Streamlit, in the log.

````
    raise self.handle_error_response(

openai.error.AuthenticationError: <empty message>

2023-05-16 10:35:17.560 Uncaught app exception

Traceback (most recent call last): ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The brief answer is you should never do such a thing as your API key will be exposed to the public.**

The correct way of doing this is specifying `environmental variables` in your deployment environment, which you'll reference in your code. As every cloud Steamlit has an established approach for this, see their docs [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I followed the instructions in the link you provided and now my web app works perfectly